# Find Earliest Date - PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I use PHP to perform SQL to pull out some data from my database between a date range. The dates are stored as date in the relation:

```
   $from = "2011-08-11";
   $to = "2011 - 08- 25";
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM `entries` WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY date ASC");
```

I would like to find the earliest date pulled from the relation.

If the query is successful, I store the 'date' attribute in a php array called $dates. I thought I could iterate over this $dates and compare the $date values after converting them into dates.

```
 if($query){
    $dates = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){      
      $dates[] = $row['date'];  
    }    

    $min = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dates[0]));
    for($i = 1; $i < count($dates); $i++){

      if($dates[i] < $min){
    $min = $dates[i];
      }
    }
```

This does not work however...It prints random values....Perhaps there is a much simpler way to do this and I am overcomplicating matters...

HEEEELLLP!!

Answer (score 3):

If you order your query, then it will be the first (or the last) row in you're query. So you wouldn't need to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$min = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dates[0]));
```

you should use

```
$min = date("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dates[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the first date since you know it is already the earliest due to `ASC` in your SQL statement. After you read the rows into your array, just use the first element.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){      
    $dates[] = $row['date'];  
} 

$earliest_date = $dates[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is find just the earliest date, and you don't care about the rest, you could use the aggregate function [min()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) in your query like so:

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS earliest FROM `entries` WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

Then just grab the `earliest` column from the result set in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates to numbers and sort the array?

Take what you have (lines 1-5),

```
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    // convert each date from "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYYMMMDD" and turn it into an int
    $date = intval(str_replace("-", "", $date));
}
// sort the array from lowest to highest
asort($dates);
// the minimum is the first item in the array
$minint = $date[0];
// convert back into "YYYY-MM-DD" format
$min = substr($minint, 0, 4) . "-" . substr($minint, 4, 6) . "-" . substr($minint, 6);
```